# Why does a character array work like a pointer in the following context

Tags: c, pointers

For the following, I can use a pointer or a char array for `scanf`:

```
char name[10];
printf("Please enter your name: ");
scanf("%9s", name);
```

And I could also do:

```
char *name = (char*)malloc(10)
printf("Please enter your name: ");
scanf("%9s", name);
```

The second one is obviously a `char*` pointer, but the first one is not -- it is an array. Why, if it's not an array and `scanf` expects a pointer am I able to do `scanf("%9s", name)` and not be forced to do `scanf("%9s", &name)`?

Comment: _but the first one is not_ , your assumption is wrong, in `C` name = &name[0]

Comment: When used in an expression context, an array id implicitly converts to a temporary pointer-to-type value, where the type is that of the underlying array, and the value is the address of the first element within the array. In the first example `&name` is a different type, btw. It is `char (*)[10]`, a pointer to an array of 10 char. The same syntax in the second example would yield a completely different type (pointer to pointer to char).

Comment: See [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay).

Comment: @tadman, just to clarify. Even if c doesn't differentiate between pointers and arrays exactly the same way as humans do, it absolute positively *do* differentiate between pointers and arrays.

Comment: @HAL9000 Oh, it does, but just not in ways that make intuitive sense. It sees them from a completely different angle.

Comment: @tadman, seeing your reputation score, I totally assume you are aware of all the internal details of arrays and pointers. But answers here are also for other readers. And sadly, there is often a misconception that pointers and arrays in c are the same.

Comment: @Iram, if `name` is an array, then `name` is not always equivalent to `&name[0]`. For instance `sizeof(name)` may not be the same as `sizeof(&name[0])`. But in a context expecting a pointer-value, then yes, they should be the same.

Comment: @tadman, as seen by this post, saying that pointers and arrays are largely interchangeable is not a good "level 1" explanation. Other than that I agree to what you are trying to say. There is a lot of c/c++ explanations that are to pedantic with their definitions, ignoring what could be a good mental model. But arrays equaling pointers is not one of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Answer (score 2):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

This is true of all array types, not just character arrays.

So when you write

```
scanf("%9s", name);
```

the *expression* `name` is converted from type "10-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and what `scanf` receives is the address of the first element of the array.

This is important - arrays are not pointers; array *expressions* are converted to pointers as necessary.

Believe it or not, there *is* a reason for this behavior.  C was derived from an earlier language called B.  In B, array objects had an explicit pointer to the first element, and the subscript operation `a[i]` was defined as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` elements from that address and dereference the result.

When designing C, Ritchie wanted to keep B’s array semantics, but he didn’t want to keep the explicit pointer to the first element that those semantics required.  So instead of creating storage for the pointer, he created the rule that the array expression is converted to a pointer expression when necessary.

And this is why arrays are weird.

Answer (score 0):

When using `"%9s"` as format specifier, `scanf` doesn't "take a pointer or an array". It only takes a pointer. What happens when you give it an array, is that the compiler does some magic. It creates a pointer to the first element of the array and gives *that* to `scanf`. So this two snippets of code are equivalent:

```
/* Snippet A */
char name[10];
scanf("%9s", name);

/* Snippet B */
char name[10];
scanf("%9s", &name[0]);
```

This does not only happen for `scanf`, but virtually every time something expects a pointer and you give it an array. A notable place where it doesn't happen, is with the `sizeof` operator.